# Tying it all together - ASP.NET with Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have an ASP.NET project (non-MVC) and I'm also using Bootstrap 3.0. This is my first time using this combination and need some guidance.

I have a gridview with a buttonfield column. Right now everything is showing up just fine with my gird and Bootstrap table formatting and its binding to my datatable - no problems there.

Next, I want to make the click of the button in the Buttonfield column to initiate a modal window and display a modal based on a unique ID from the row button that opened it.

I don't really know how to tie this all together with ASP.NET and Bootstrap. HTML literals? Dynamic ASP.NET panels? It doesn't matter to me whether there is a postback or not, I'd really just like some guidance or even pseudo-code on how these can be tied together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OP specifically requested **bootstrap** help...

You should go through the bootstrap documentation for modals http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

It makes no difference if you are using MVC or not and you should not need to do any kind of post back to display the modal.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" />
```

Will trigger element with id myModal to be shown.

Using bootstrap's own demo code in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/1057/) demonstrates opening and dismissing the modal.

For the second part of the question, this [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/1062/) shows how you can also use the button click event to set a value in the modal. You could do other actions in that event handler like get or send data to the backend or change other elements in the modal.

For your case, you would want to handle all button clicks in a single event handler but you can store the id in a custom attribute on the button element. I like to use custom attributes instead of parsing from name, id, or class attributes. This is the bootstrap convention.

```
$(function() {
  $('button.btn').on('click', function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('data-value')
    $('div.modal').find('#target').text(value);
  });
});
```

Here I have broken out how to get the custom attribute value from the button instance which was clicked.

Post what you have so far and what you still can't get working.

This also shouldn't be tagged with C# or asp.net as that is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks, that's along the lines of what I was hoping for. But the C# side of it is relevant because now I need to tie together the second part of my question. How do I distinguish which button opened the modal? Its a grid with 50+ records so I need to be able to pass a unique ID to the modal.

Comment: I've updated with some more details. You probably want to avoid adding 50+ divs for each modal and just update, show one. Note that bootstrap modal does not support multiple modals showing at once.

Answer (score 0):

You might need a simple js function to take care of that(as mike mentioned this has nothing to do with using or not using bootstrap since it is just some css stuff):

```
var RunDialog;
$(document).ready(function () {
    RunDialog = $("#Id").dialog();
});
```

Comment: OK. And how would I tie this to the bound button in the field?

Comment: #Id is the Id of the element that you want to use for displaying the dialog, if it is like a grid with multiple buttons, you can give them all the same class name and use that class name as the selector like: $("myButtonClass").dialog();

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ASP.Net Ajax ModalPopup](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) for ASP.Net Web Form. You can google a lot of examples regarding GridView with ModelPopup.

[ModalPopupExtender inside a GridView ItemTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6046504/296861)

> I want to make the click of the button in the Buttonfield column to
>   initiate a modal window and display a modal based on a unique ID from
>   the row button that opened it.

ModalPopup should work with Bootstrap.